# MIPS: how can I store data in an adress?

Tags: assembly, mips, simulator, mars-simulator

I need to know that how can I pick a certain address to store my data.

For example, as you can see in the image, how can I store `4` in `0x20` instead of `0`?

[image: MARS simulator adresses]

Comment: This is pretty much the first day of the course. Have you looked at the `sw` instruction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without using pseudoinsctructions

```
lui  $s1, 0x0000
ori  $s1, $s1, 0x0020
addi $s2, $zero, 4
sw   $s2, ($s1)
```

---

if the answer works for you hit that accepted answer tick:)

Comment: Uh no. You missed the store and the `lui` `ori` combination is redundant.

Comment: @KonradLindenbach yes thanks for the assistance. My bad!

Comment: Why not just `ori $s1, $zero, 0x20`?

Comment: it's more flexible for adresses bigger than 16bits

Comment: but yeah i could just use `ori`